# Extra Cost of Azure Red Hat OpenShift

Tags: azure, openshift

Recently, I need to prepare for the budget of having a minimal scale of Azure Red Hat OpenShift. I would like to ask any other cost and how much about these extra cost, apart form the VM cost, OpenShift License cost and SSD Disk costs?

Below is the cost I already know:

- Master x3: Reserved VM Instance, Standard_D8s_v3 + Premium SSD P30
- Worker x3: Reserved VM Instance, Standard_D4s_v3 + Premium SSD P15
- OpenShift x3: Azure Red Hat OpenShift General Purpose, 4 vCPU

So, any other extra cost which I need know?

Answer (score 1):

A few other things to consider:

- Usually OpenShift also includes [Infrastructure nodes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/machine_management/creating-infrastructure-machinesets.html), I would
  suggest having some since server costs are lower than license costs. OpenShift subscriptions are counted on worker node vCPU only, masters and infrastructure nodes are excluded.
- Depending on your workloads, you may also need to account for an
  Azure storage to support PVCs or possibly something like [Red Hat
  Data Foundations](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift-data-foundation).
- I would also suggest to look into something for secret storage such as [Azure Key Value](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/key-vault/)

Comment: Thanks! With the information from Red Hat sales, based on my requirements, some extra cost maybe the PVCs and the Azure Standard NLB.